# Matplotlib throws memory error when trying to meshgrid on big arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a rectangular grid out of xy array using the following code in Matplotlib. My `nx = 12720` and `ny = 10117`

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
nx, ny = range_samples, azimuth_lines  # 12720, 10117
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny)). # MEMORY ERROR
x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
points = np.vstack((x, y)).T
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
path = Path(sar_ver)
grid = path.contains_points(points)
```

Is there any other library I can use to do this operation? Any ideas on fixing it will be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting a memory error from the `meshgrid` line? I doubt that.

Comment: Yes, from the meshgrid.

Comment: how much memory do you have? I think this grid should result in ~1 GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, fixed it by killing heavy running processes. There was one process that was using a lot of memory. This was nothing related to Matplotlib. Let me know if I have to delete this question. It was a little silly on my part!

Comment: No you don't have to delete it, but you may if you wish. Think about it in terms of if and how this can be useful for future readers. If you come to the conclusion that future readers do not make such silly mistakes, you may delete it. Else, you may edit the question and answer to include a bit more detail on what the problem was and why you were not able to solve it initially. Use words that would then allow people to find this through search in similar cases.